# Wrap and remove extra characters

Tags: javascript, html, css

is there a way to remove unwrappable characters which cant fit inside an Element.

For example-

if there is a list with specific width-

```
<ul>
    <li>First word</li>
    <li>This is a long long long word</li>
    <li>Another word</li>
</ul>
```

with this Style-

```
ul li
{
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Then, the long item text will be wrapped into second line.

How can I remove the extra un-wrappable words/characters ?

**Here is the Fiddle:** [**http://jsfiddle.net/N9ct3/1/**](http://jsfiddle.net/N9ct3/1/)

**Edit:** There can be multiple list-items with different width- So, substring by counting the characters- might not be a solution & also **workable for ie8+**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding text-ellipsis for exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/N9ct3/2/

```
ul li
{
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:lightblue;
    border:1px solid black;

    //Avoid text overflow by adding "..."
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the css rule `overflow: hidden;` to the list items.

```
ul li
{
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:lightblue;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```